# Is it intentional that cmp::Eq is implemented for fn(&'a T) -> T but not fn(&T) -> T?

Tags: rust

Take the following valid snippet in Rust 1.25.0:

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;

trait Foo {
    type Eq: Eq;
}

struct Bar<'a>(PhantomData<&'a u8>);

impl<'a> Foo for Bar<'a> {
    type Eq = fn(&'a u32) -> u32;
}
```

As seen on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=5d9ab88c05134ac95614847f7ef51f01&version=undefined), this shows that `Eq` is implemented for `fn(&'a T) -> T`.

If we make a very small change, removing the lifetime of the associated type:

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;

trait Foo {
    type Eq: Eq;
}

struct Bar<'a>(PhantomData<&'a u8>);

impl<'a> Foo for Bar<'a> {
    type Eq = fn(&u32) -> u32;
}
```

We can [see](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=d0f40826a98e2afff0a9e52af3f15cd2&version=undefined) that `Eq` is not implemented for `fn(&u32) -> u32`:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `for<'r> fn(&'r u32) -> u32: std::cmp::Eq` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:9:10
  |
9 | impl<'a> Foo for Bar<'a> {
  |          ^^^ the trait `std::cmp::Eq` is not implemented for `for<'r> fn(&'r u32) -> u32`
  |
  = help: the following implementations were found:
            <extern "C" fn(A) -> Ret as std::cmp::Eq>
            <unsafe fn(A) -> Ret as std::cmp::Eq>
            <extern "C" fn(A, ...) -> Ret as std::cmp::Eq>
            <unsafe extern "C" fn(A, ...) -> Ret as std::cmp::Eq>
          and 2 others
```

Is this intentional, an oversight and should be implemented, or a bug?
If it's the first, what are the reasons for not doing it?

Looking at [the source code for `fn`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.25.0/src/libcore/ptr.rs#L2163), we see that they implement `PartialEq` using raw pointer equivalence, i.e. if the address is the same, it must be the same function. Why would this not hold for `fn(&T) -> T`?

One option that has been presented to me is that `fn(&T) -> T` is generic over the lifetime of the argument and cannot therefore be logically `Eq`. `fn(&'a T) -> T` is not generic, as the lifetime has been specified to be `'a`. I'm not quite sure I accept/understand this hypothesis so if anyone has a good argument for it I would accept that too.

Comment: *`fn(&'a T) -> T` is not generic* — yes, it is. `'a` is a generic lifetime parameter. Thus that line of reasoning does not seem to hold up.

Answer (score 2):

Probably because when you compare two `fn(&T) -> T`, you're really comparing an `fn(&'a T) -> T` with an `fn(&'b T) -> T` with no way to check that the lifetimes `'a` and `'b` are the same, whereas when you compare two `fn(&'a T) -> T`, you know that the lifetimes are the same.

Note: this is only a supposition on my part, I have no authoritative information on the matter.

Comment: Wouldn't two `fn(&T) -> T` be `fn<'b>(&'b T) -> T` and `fn<'c>(&'c T) -> T`? And would you ever have two functions like those be different functions, i.e. wouldn't they be implemented as the same one?

Comment: At the time you compare them they are no longer generic: all generic parameters (including lifetimes) have been resolved. If all generic parameters have been resolved to be the same, then they can be compared. Othewise it doesn't make sense to compare them (for the same reason you can't compare an `u8` and an `u32`).

Comment: I see the point on a type theory basis, but would it ever resolve to 2 different functions? Additionally, would there be any unsafety in manually implementing `Eq` with pointer equivalence using newtypes?